# How do I section website with pictures/background colors?

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a site created all in Photoshop and I am trying to translate it in HTML/CSS and I am having a little trouble on a few styling things I was wondering how do I section the website with multiple background images/color like I was thinking I could do this with divs but I don't think that is working anyway any/all relevant help would be appreciated

A quick idea of what I mean is

### Nav bar

*BG Image1

Content

---

BG image2

content
_------------

footer

Comment: Welcome to SO Devin! You have to post some code and to explain what went wrong, otherwise no one can help you. Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it may help, cheers!

Comment: why not use DIVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm nut sure what would you like, but based on your pseudo plan I can imagine something like this:

```
<div id="nav">NAV</div>
<div id="div1"><p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quam. Vivamus aptent sodales lorem, tempus vel duis sapien id fusce, eu tincidunt. Vel orci pharetra nulla penatibus. Lacus eget a. Eu est vel maecenas et, curabitur sed integer nibh, molestie nulla </p>
<p>
Mi et, a tellus quis nonummy ultricies egestas quis, elementum lacus aenean pellentesque nisl, quam aenean. Enim quis iaculis, adipiscing volutpat et vestibulum molestie sit, morbi quis sit duis mauris, pellentesque tincidunt 
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

#div1{
  background-image: url("https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg");
}

#div2{
  background-image: url("http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg");
}
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ypncww57/2/

Without gat between divs:
https://jsfiddle.net/ypncww57/3/

Comment: The align attribute of <p> is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code! lorem-ipsum generators.. :)

Comment: Perfect this is exactly what i meant but how do I get rid of spaces between?images

Comment: add to css: p{
  margin: 0;
}

Comment: If I were to have a small bit of text and tried to put a background image the image comes off very small and line breaks make it bigger and more fuller however its different full screen and half screen how can I 
1. Make it bigger w/o line breaks
2.Keep it all positioned the same on devices

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague, but anyway, you can use the div or the section tag and style them via CSS to your heart contents

Answer (score 0):

1.) There is a `<section>` element in HTML5 to which you can assign background images via CSS (using classes or IDs). You can wrap your existing DIVs and other elements in those `section`tags.

2.) If you don't like that, you can still use DIVs to wrap your sections, and style these (using classes or IDs) via CSS.